# How to create HERE maps

Tags: here-api

HERE maps for certain city like Chennai, India is very limited. I understand that lot of information can be added so that it will benefit end-user.

My question, can I create a new map using HERE and allow my version of maps to be downloaded? If yes? How can I do this

Comment: I didn't understand the question exactly ? What kind of information are you looking to add ? Are they POIs ? You can add simple Markers to show POIs of your interest.   Example :  https://developer.here.com/api-explorer#maps-js/markers-on-the-map  or do you want to add an overlay over HERE map ?  Example : https://developer.here.com/api-explorer#maps-js/custom-tile-overlay

Comment: Create new maps altogether for certain locations

Comment: If i understood you want to create maps from the scratch ? This is not supported by HERE. you can overlay tiles but you cannot remove here maps and create you own map instead, check Terms and Condition https://developer.here.com/terms-and-conditions  "7. Use of Results, Content, Layering, Commingling"

Answer (score 0):

HERE Maps is a proprietary software so you can not try to recreate your own version of it. Trying to recreate a Map API by yourself is a cool idea, but it is also a good idea to build something on top of a technology or an application that is already existing. There are other Map API's out there like [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/about) and [Google Maps](https://www.google.com.ph/maps) that allows user to create and add data about POIs (Point of Interests) and/or locations. The data on these apps are also open source, that is why the community are encouraged to contribute data of their own on top of the Application.

TIP: If you are really onto it here is a page that documents the stuffs the happened behind the scenes in developing the HERE Maps: http://360.here.com/2014/12/11/video-craft-science-behind-maps/